# js - how can I detect some old or unsupport broswers with pop up message?

Tags: javascript, browser, version, user-agent, detect

I hope user don't use all IE, opera Mini, (plus China browsers) to browse my site. And Edge version large than 12, firefox large than 38.8, chrome large than 40, safari large than 9, opera large than 40.

Comment: use feature detection

Comment: what is the significance of those browser versions? Edge 12, Firefox 38.8, Chrum 40, Safari 9 and Opera 40? Seems almost arbitrary version numbers, what made you choose those in particular? note: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ch8y9551/) is ES2015+ feature detection code that doesn't "throw" - if that's the reason you want to deter older browsers

Answer (score 1):

If statements are a great way to display content for specific versions Internet Explorer or Chrome. You can also use such statements to detect if it is version is lesser than 38.8 then either show the popup.

```
<!--[if Browser Version]>
Special instructions for the Browser
<![endif]-->
```

Also checkout https://browser-update.org/

Browser update is a tool for unobtrusively notifying visitors that they should update their web browser in order to use your website.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the User Agent on your server and send the error responses for requests from unsupported browser.

However, it would be better practice to use Feature Detection on the client as Jaromanda X suggested in their comment. [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) is a good CSS and JS library which can help you get started. They also have a good explanation on [what Feature Detection is](https://modernizr.com/docs/#what-is-feature-detection) in the first place.

[Outdated Browser](http://outdatedbrowser.com/en/how) is also an option you could explore.